# How do I get user input from cin into C++11 std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

How can I get input from the user into the `std::array`?

This is what I have but it will not compile.

```
std::array<char, 10> myArray{"hello"} ;
std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
std::cin >> myArray;
```

If more than 10 characters are entered, truncate and ignore them.  I would also need the cin buffer cleared to allow for other input later on.

Comment: What do you want to happen if more than 10 characters are entered?

Comment: truncate and ignore them. I would also need the cin buffer cleared to allow for other input later on.

Answer (score 5):

For your current example you should use `std::string` instead of `std::array<char, 10>`. However, if you still want to read an array you could do it as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main() {
    std::array<int, 10> arr;
    for(int temp, i = 0; i < arr.size() && std::cin >> temp; ++i) {
        arr[i] = temp;
    }

    for(auto&& i : arr) {
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

The basic idea is to just loop over until the array size and then insert it into the array using its `operator[]`. You keep the `std::cin >> temp` in the loop condition to catch errors in the insertion process. Note that there isn't a built-in function in the standard library that does this for you.

If you do find yourself doing this often, you could move it into your own function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template<typename T, size_t N>
std::istream& input_array(std::istream& in, std::array<T, N>& arr) {
    unsigned i = 0u;
    for(T temp; i < arr.size() && in >> temp; ++i) {
        arr[i] = std::move(temp);
    }
    return in;
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 10> arr;
    input_array(std::cin, arr);
}
```

You shouldn't overload `operator>>` for things inside the `std` namespace since that's undefined behaviour.

If you want to avoid the temporary you could modify the function as follows:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
std::istream& input_array(std::istream& in, std::array<T, N>& arr) {
    for(unsigned i = 0u; i < arr.size() && in >> arr[i]; ++i) { 
        // empty body
    }
    return in;
}
```

Comment: Just me being picky: the helper function makes an unnecessary copy from `temp` to `arr[i]`.

Comment: @GabrielGarcia It's unavoidable. You could use `std::move` to ask to do a move but at the end of the day, either a copy or a move will have to be made.

Comment: Maybe this? `while (i < N && in) in >> arr[i++];`

Comment: @GabrielGarcia With a little modification that could work. I've edited the answer to take that into account.

Comment: Found out that since C++11 the expected behavior of failed extractions is to zero-out the reference passed (not sure if this behavior is expected from user overloads of >>). This means the code I proposed could zero-out an element in the user's array. I suppose this is ok, considering it's the same behavior as standard >> overloads. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt

Answer (score 1):

Just use the proper tool for the job:

```
std::string name;
std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aca343bd71a580cf)

Comment: **Jeffrey** Even though this is correct for certain purposes, the OP is not asking this.

Comment: @cell I think (I might be mistaken) that he is asking how to receive a string input. This assumption is made on the label written to the standard output before the input is requested: "Enter your name: ". I also assume he read somewhere that he should have done that with `char[]` for proper ~performance~, and then he probably read something about `std::array` and put them together; which is awful.

Comment: @cell In case I'm wrong, I would love to hear what is the semantic of what he is trying to do with that fixed sized array, as well as some other small things like if a shorter string should also store the null character in the array or what about overflowing, etc...

Comment: **Jeffrey** ok, but I think that the answer by Vlad From Moscow answers in more appropriate way what the OP is asking.

Comment: @cell No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can upvote the answers you find useful by clicking on the up arrow next to the answer; you can also (after some initial reputation) downvote answers you find not useful by clicking on the down arrow. You can do the same with questions to help the community sort trough well written questions. Other informations can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Don't forget to start [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour); you get a badge for that! :)

Comment: I am just trying to understand the c++ 11 array style, no more than that. That code snipet is the program. All of the examples online show design time data input but no run time user input. Based on the responses, I am not understanding the benefit in the new standard. Thank you for all of the comments!

Comment: @dmaelect You are simply using the wrong container for the task at hand. Reading data of size determined at runtime into an array whose size is determined at compile time is foolish.

Comment: @ juanchopanza Do you have an example of the correct way to get user input into this style of array? Again, I am just trying to understand how it works and how it is implemented?

Comment: `operator>>` is probably incorrect, since names can contain spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Requires `<iostream>` and `<limits>` headers.

```
std::cin.get(myArray.data(), myArray.size());
// get() will actually read up to myArray.size() - 1 chars
// and add a null character at the end ('\0')

if (std::cin.fail()) {
    // could not read any characters or EOF occurred
} else {
    // drop rest of line that was read to buffer
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    // number of characters read: std::cin.gcount()

    // ... use myArray ...
}
```

Method references:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/fail

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount

Answer (score 0):

You can get the whole line into a buffer, and then extract the first 10 bytes of that buffer (or the whole buffer if it was shorter than 10) into your array. This also solves the problem of not having any junk left around on `std::cin`.

```
std::array<char, 10> myArray{"hello"} ;

std::string s;
std::getline( std::cin, s );
if ( !std::cin )
     throw.....   // input was closed before a line was entered

std::size_t len = std::min( myArray.size(), s.size() );
std::copy(s.begin(), s.begin() + len, myArray.begin() );
```

Note that this does not create a null-terminated string in `myArray`. If you want to do that, then copy one extra character (and make `len` be at most `myArray.size() - 1`).

May require to include `<array>`, `<iostream>`, `<algorithm>`

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is expecting a char pointer (`char*`) in this case. So you need to use `.data()`.

```
std::array<char, 50> arr{"Hello, "};
size_t hello_length = strlen(arr.data());

std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
std::cin >> std::setw(10) >> (arr.data() + hello_length);

std::cout << arr.data() << std::endl;
```

Comment: @MatthiasB, wouldn't adding `std::setw` help?

Answer (score 0):

In C++, array's pointer is first element's address.
For `std::array`, We can get input by array's pointer.

```
std::cin >> myArray.begin();
```